# Hard drive issues... i think

Tags: troubleshooting

I have an Acer Aspire 5239 laptop that's been giving me issues.

When i first got it it ran very well and was fairly quick running Windows 7 Home 64-bit on 2GB of DDR3 RAM. Well it crashed roughly 2 years after and ended up having to replace the 250GB SATA HDD with a warranty replacement which was a WD Blue Caviar 250GB 5200RPM. Same as was in it before.

After installing Windows Ultimate from my desktop computer (because the laptop didnt come with any restore software), it was extremely slow so it got put up for a couple years until my son asked me for it.

I was thinking it was a RAM issue so I replaced the 2GB with 8GB (2x4GB) of compatible memory. Windows Ultimate recognized the upgrade so I know the RAM works, but Windows was still slow.

I went to the Acer store and bought their system recovery disks for that specific laptop to try to do a complete factory reset. All was going fine until disk 3. When the restore got to 80%, I got a "Cyclic redundancy error".

I called Acer and they told me to try to run disks again and still didn't work, giving me the same error at the same point of the restore. At this point they said there was nothing else they could help me, since the laptop was out of warranty.

So I ran DBAN to try to save the drive and wipe it clean thinking maybe something was corrupted or malicious on the disk keeping me from installing the Acer recovery disk for Windows 7. I ran autonuke and it took about 5.5 hours to complete with no errors and said there was 223GB available space.

So I ran the recovery disks again and got the same cyclic redundancy error at the 80% mark. I probably have a bad hard drive but want to know for sure before I buy new. Is there any way to run a bootable disk like DBAN to check the HDD? If so, are there any known that are free that work well?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Unfortunately, I don't have high hopes for that hard disk; see my answer below.  When you post in the future, please try and make your question easily readable (new paragraphs, capitalization) and short.  You did thoroughly troubleshoot before asking the question, which we very much appreciate.  Hopefully you continue on with SuperUser and volunteer some answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, my experience is that once a hard drive experiences any error whatsoever, it is no longer trustworthy.  You already tried a factory reset, so you don't mind losing the data on it.  Therefore, purchase a replacement HD, swap it in, and then run the factory reset to install the standard OS.  Beware, sometimes not all hard drives are supported by motherboard, so make sure you can return the disk.